# Flutter iOS: How to fix "Could not build module `firebase_core`"?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have a flutter projecct. First it had to work on android and its working! Everything is cool. Time to make it work on iOS but I get the following error when I try to start the project on iOS Simulator:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           13,1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/ew/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-10.0.6/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:6:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/ew/Dev/projects/SWIE%20-%20ink%20-%20mobil/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_core/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
    In file included from /Users/ew/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.8.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:12:
    /Users/ew/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.8.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:9:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin': '/Users/ew/Dev/projects/SWIE%20-%20ink%20-%20mobil/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]

--------------------------------- HERE --------------------------------

    #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    /Users/ew/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-10.0.6/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:6:9: fatal error: could not build module 'firebase_core'

--------------------------------- HERE --------------------------------
    #import <firebase_core/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    2 errors generated.
    While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/ew/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-10.0.6/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:6:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/ew/Dev/projects/SWIE%20-%20ink%20-%20mobil/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_core/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
    In file included from /Users/ew/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.8.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:12:
    /Users/ew/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.8.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:9:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin': '/Users/ew/Dev/projects/SWIE%20-%20ink%20-%20mobil/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
    #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    /Users/ew/Dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-10.0.6/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:6:9: fatal error: could not build module 'firebase_core'
    #import <firebase_core/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    2 errors generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.3.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Sadly I did not find any working solution for this...

This is my pubspec.yaml (firebase dependencies):

```
  firebase_performance: ^0.7.0+7
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.1.1
  firebase_core: any
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.6
  flutter_local_notifications: ^8.1.1+2
```

Answer (score 7):

Remove **ios/Pods** folder.

Remove **Podfile** and **Podfile.lock**

Remove **pubspec.lock**

Open terminal and run these commands one after another

```
cd ios
pod cache clean --all
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod install
```

Comment: while following your instructions, at the last part I got this error `[!] No Podfile' found in the project directory.`

Comment: U need to cd into the ios folder

Comment: the command should `pod cache clean  --all` with two dashes

Comment: Many thanks for this info @Boken/Hurab ... I did each of the above just now and then the underlying errors went away ... Perfect : )

Answer (score 0):

In pubspec.yaml add `firebase_core:any` . Then run `flutter clean` , `flutter pub get`. Then navigate to iOS folder from the project root directory in terminal `cd ios`. Then run `pod install`. Now run `flutter run` and it should work as expected.

Comment: I done these but I still have the same problem.

Comment: In your terminal run
`rm -r ~/.pub-cache`
please note that this will delete the .pub-cache folder in your system. Delete the Podfile.lock and then `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and then `pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is using the precompiled version for the Firestore iOS SDK as something went wrong during compilation. See 'Improve iOS Build Times' section at https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initializing-flutterfire

1. Remove all pod installations that have to do with firebase from your
   podfile (e.g. pod 'Firebase/Analytics').
2. Add the precompiled pod to your podfile (see link above).

I've added `pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.7.0'` to the runner target in the podfile (this is an older version as the newer also gave some error).

The result looks like this in your podfile:

````
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.7.0'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end```
````

Answer (score -1):

this error is coming from .pub-cache so just flutter clean, if the error still persist delete all the .pub-cache then

> Remove the package from dependencies in pubspec.yaml, run flutter
> packages get. And then add the package to dependencies again and
> running flutter packages get.This process has solved the problem for
> me in the past.

flutter clean

and pub get