# Multiple Firebase errors in Xcode

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting these weird errors when I'm building in Xcode. I'm using flutter. I've tried deleting my .xcworkspace and using flutter clean. I've searched multiple answers but none of them work. Please help.

[image]

Comment: You need the .xcodeworkspace. Have you accidentlly opened the .xcodeproj?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69813789/2641242

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter iOS: How to fix "Could not build module \`firebase\_core\`"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69813789/flutter-ios-how-to-fix-could-not-build-module-firebase-core)

Comment: I got another error. But I'm looking for a solution.'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found